# Is there any way to add a description to a file while pushing it for the first time in git?

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I push a file for the first time in the GIT repository, can I add a short description about that file? (for example, what does the file contain, when to modify the file, etc.)

I know we can add a description file in for the repository, but I wanted to add a description to individual files.

Comment: add the description in the commit message.

Comment: I knew this would be one of the answers! :) The commit message would not be visible easily (at least on sites like bitbucket/github) as it would be overridden with the next commit

Answer (score 1):

`git` doesn't maintain any sort of "description" of a file, nor does it maintain similar information about a repository as a whole.  Some services (like GitHub or Bitbucket) may treat a file specially (for example, GitHub will treat several variants of `README` and will display this by default when browsing the repository).

The best way to document the file is to provide an appropriate commit message when you first add the file to the repository.  This commit message is easy to retrieve using something like:

```
git log --diff-filter=A myfile
```

This asks `git` to only display commits where the file `myfile` was added `--diff-filter=A`.

Comment: Yes, this could help. I was searching for a more UI readable way though. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can change it after the remote (bare) repository exists.

Write direct to the file like this:

```
ssh gitserver 'echo "My new description" > /path/to/description'
```

This assumes that:

- Server is running linux.
- You know the path to the git repository on the server (likely) see your remote path (git remote -v).
- Git access to server is set up using ssh.
- The repository has already been pushed.